# Do a calculated Column via Powershell

Tags: powershell

Still new in using Powershell.

I more or less just want to do the following:

I have a customername and a customernumber.
In a third column I want the following "Customername - Customernumber"

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need powershell for that. Just create a calculated column at your  list with this formula.

```
=CONCATENATE(CustomerName;"-";CustomerNumber)
```

P.S. : You would need to change ; to ,

Also here is PowerShell script. It works for me.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell –ErrorAction SilentlyContinue


#Variables
$WebURL="http://MySharePointSite/sites/Dev/"
$ListName="CalcTest"
$CalculatedColumnName="Cust"

#Get the Web
$web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL

#Get the List
$list = $web.Lists.TryGetList($ListName)

#Add new calculated column
$list.Fields.Add($CalculatedColumnName, "Calculated", $false)

#Get the column
$CalculatedCol = $List.Fields.GetField($CalculatedColumnName)
#Set Formula for calculated column 
$CalculatedCol.Formula='=CONCATENATE([CustomerName];"-";[CustomerNumber])'
$CalculatedCol.OutputType="Text"
$CalculatedCol.Update()

$web.Dispose()
```

[More info](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/03/add-calculated-column-to-sharepoint-list-using-powershell.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Using such a column is exactly what I need to avoid, since a third party application doenst really like them ;) 

Ill try your script tho! Seems simple enough that it should work!